# What is the difference in a webpack loader separated with an ! symbol vs listing out the array in quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, webpack

Webpack [documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#referencing-loaders) suggest that the following syntax is equal

```
{
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jade$/, loader: "jade" },
            // => "jade" loader is used for ".jade" files

            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            // => "style" and "css" loader is used for ".css" files
            **// Alternative syntax:**
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ["style", "css"] },
        ]
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to hold true always and I am wondering what the difference is...

For my app I added a loader with this configuration...

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!sass-loader")
},
```

what I would like to do is not have the "style-loader" separated from the other 2 loaders... However, when I create the configuration and run it I get the following error with this configuration.

```
 {
     test: /\.scss$/,
     exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
     loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader")
 },

ERROR in ./src/file.scss
Module build failed: ReferenceError: window is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/mbp06/Repos/propertymarketing/frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/Users/mbp06/Repos/propertymarketing/frontend/node_modules/css-loader/in
```

This syntax works as expected...

```
{
     test: /\.scss$/,
     loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
},
```

Comment: Hmmm, from initial research it does seem like the two different forms of syntax are supposed to be the same; I imagine the ! delimited string is just split into an array when webpack runs anyways. I wonder if the ExtractTextPlugin is causing some sort of conflict.. Any reason in particular you don't want to use the array syntax?

Comment: Loader authors use [`loader-utils`](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils) to handle the three different forms of how loaders can be configured and chained. I'm confused why the loader string `'style!css!sass'` wouldn't have worked.

Comment: I figured it out i am going to write an explanation soon.